Microservice doesn't map ports correctly on Kafka
My microservice application throws a continuous error while trying to use Kafka. I am testing several configuration possibilities and I cannot understand why it doesn't work.
Configuration of microservice:
# Kafka general configuration
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092

docker-compose.yml
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.7.0
    ports:
      - "9092:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

Per my understanding:

My application connects to localhost:9092
docker-compose.yml has included mapping host:container ports which is 9092 (host where we connect):9093 (port which we access within container)

Expected result:
Kafka port is correctly mapped - application uses localhost:9092 which is mapped on port 9093 on Kafka therefore allowing us to use it properly
Actual result:
An error is thrown
2024-06-01T14:13:11.354+02:00  WARN 9560 --- [event] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-example_group-1, groupId=example_group] Connection to node 1001 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-06-01T14:13:12.282+02:00  INFO 9560 --- [event] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-example_group-1, groupId=example_group] Node 1001 disconnected.

If I use one port everywhere, it works correctly. But I want to test out other possibilites.

Your program is only going to work if you use the same port everywhere; how else do you except your whole program to interact with the API or whatever else you have in your program?

Kafka returns the advertised listener back to the client, so it's accepting the port mapping for the initial connection  then ignoring it

That being said, you could duplicate the config PLAINTEXT_1://localhost:9093, PLAINTEXT_2://localhost:9092 and add listener protocol mapping config, and then the port mapping should work
